# Can I use a web.py session outside of the browser?

Tags: python, web.py

I have been developing a web app using web.py. It uses a session like below:

```
store = web.session.DBStore(db.sess, "sessions")
session = web.session.Session(
    app,
    store,
    initializer={
        "auth": False,
        "username": "anonymous",
        "preferences": db.data.select('preferences', where="username='anonymous'", limit=1)[0]
    }
)
web.config._session = session
```

I decided, it could be useful to have a desktop application as well. A problem I am running into though, is I cannot get a session to work properly outside of a web browser. I believe it's just another object that holds specific data, but I am not entirely sure.

What I need is some way to either use web.py to create a session so I can use all of my functions with it (many check for a session to see who is logged in) or I need some way to create a "fake" session containing essentially the same data as before so I could still use the functions.

My whole goal in this is to keep using the same model, since then I wouldn't have to rewrite many functions that just duplicate functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong. Turns out web.input needs context, which is not available outside of the browser as far as I could see.

What I ended up doing was changing my `login(...)` method from `login(input)` to `login(username, password)`. Now, from the interactive shell, I can get a session. I believe this will carry over into a desktop application as the interactive shell is not a browser.